# API Controller method occasionally called multiple times?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have an API Controller method that sometimes takes a considerably long time to process => 10+ minutes.  On occasion the method gets called again server side.  I verified that the UI is not making additional calls as a sanity check.  There are no errors in my error log tables nor is the event viewer picking up anything abnormal.  Is there an IIS setting or a config setting that might cause this?

NOTE: This has been observed to happen every 5 minutes unless the process completes before then.

```
[HttpPost]
public void GenerateAndStore1095Cs(int tokenValue, int organizationId, int taxYear)
{
    AuthenticateAndRecord(
                tokenValue, 
                nameof(GenerateAndStore1095Cs), 
                nameof(GenerateAndStore1095Cs), 
                organizationId);

    PDFBusiness.GenerateAndStore1095Cs(organizationId, taxYear);
}
```

Comment: `I verified that the UI is not making additional calls as a sanity check.` Could the user be clicking the submit button multiple times?

Comment: @mjwills I asked myself that as well.  The button is disabled upon click, and only enabled once callback is complete.

Comment: When it gets called multiple times at once, what is the offending user agent (i.e. which web browser)?

Comment: I've seen similar behaviour when debugging on IIS (the request is resent if you spend too much time on breakpoints) - are you caching the requests? Have you tried to force cache to be disabled, either by setting the headers in IIS or in your code?

Comment: @mjwills I have tested in both Chrome and IE

Comment: @Kolichikov I have not.  Do you happen to have an example as to what you're suggesting?

Comment: Here's a link to how to do cache control on IIS (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache). I'm not sure if it'll help, but it's worth a look. Also, are you using a load balancer by any chance? Those also might have settings to retry long running requests (see here for instance: https://serverfault.com/questions/532120/f5-load-balancer-resends-request-on-timeout)

Comment: @Kolichikov

I added 

    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
    </staticContent>

to my api project config.  Does this need to go in the main site config though?